# vim function external call

Tags: function, rspec, cucumber, vim

Currently my vimrc has the following key mappings:

```
map <leader>m :w\|!clear && rspec --drb %<cr>
map <leader>k :w\|!clear && rspec --drb %:<C-r>=line('.')<CR><cr>
map <leader>c :w\|:!clear && cucumber --drb -r ./features %<cr>
map <leader>x :w\|!clear && cucumber --drb -r ./features %:<C-r>=line('.')<CR><cr>
```

However I want to consolidate them into (two) functions that have the same keymap for line vs file, I've tried the following but Vim complains about missing parentheses:

```
function! TestCurrentLine()
  let spec = '*_spec\.rb'
  if !(expand("%") =~ spec)
    :!clear && cucumber --drb -r ./features %:<C-r>=line('.')<CR>
  else
    :!clear && rspec --drb %:<C-r>=line('.')<CR>
  end
endfunction

function! TestCurrentFile()
  let spec = '*_spec\.rb'
  if !(expand("%") =~ spec)
    :!clear && cucumber --drb -r ./features %
  else
    :!clear && rspec --drb %
  end
endfunction

map <leader>m :w\|call TestCurrentFile<cr>
map <leader>k :w\|call TestCurrentLine<cr>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parentheses to your function calls:

```
map <leader>m :w\|call TestCurrentFile()<cr>
map <leader>k :w\|call TestCurrentLine()<cr>
```

Answer (score 4):

apart from the missed `()` in your map command. Your functions have some problems too:

- `!clear` you don't need the leading `:`
- `'*_spec\.rb'` is supposed to be a regex. but the leading `*` doesn't make any sense. you want to have `.*_spe.....`? also better with `.*_spec\.rb$'`
- pass `%` directly to your shell command is not 100% safe. (if your buffer name has special chars or spaces). you could use the build-in `shellescape()` function. For example, `shellescape(@%,1)`  (then you need `"execute"` to  execute the command)
- consider to create those mapping only for certain filetype (via autocmd) in certain buffer (`<buffer>`), also when creating mapping,  consider "nore".

Comment: +1 for `nnoremap <buffer>`. I would also suggest if the `filetype` isn't set correctly to `cucubmer` or `rspec` to using an autocommand like this `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *_spec.rb set filetype=cucumber`. Check the filetype via `set filetype?`. Properly setting the filetype will give more than just syntax hightlighting. It will also give you access to `:make`. You can set the compiler directly via `:compiler cucumber` or `:compiler rspec` if you need. I recommend learning to use the `quickfix` list to move through the `:make` results.

Comment: I've re-written the command completely already, but I will definitely look at the filetype specific loading, thanks.